# How do we show that $(0,0)$ is the only equilibrium point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

For the following system,
$$
x'=x-y-x^3
$$
$$
y'=x+y-y^3
$$
I get solve that $(0,0)$ is the equilibrium. But how do we show that $(0,0)$ is the only equilibrium point?

That means we need to solve
$$
x-y-x^3=0
$$
$$
x+y-y^3=0
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** From the second equation, we have $$x = y^3-y$$

Substitute that into the first equation, expand and get a ninth-order equation in $y$ only.

It only has a  single real root $y = 0$, and then use that in the above to find $x$.

The other eight roots are imaginary.

Comment: How to say that ninth-order equation in $y$ only has a single real root $y=0$?

Comment: Can we just convert it into polar coordinate? It becomes $r'=r-r^3[1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(2\theta)]$. So the only equilibrium is $r=0$?

Comment: Because there is only one real root and eight imaginary roots for a total of nine. Sure, if you can convert into something simpler, that works too.